# Deletion of sent mail from outlook

Tags: vb.net, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

How to delete sent mail from outlook using UiPath? I used Delete Exchange Mail Message activity to delete the mail message. I got an error `Delete Exchange Mail Message: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Is there is any other way to delete the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the emails from Sent folder to Deleted folder? USe Move Outlook Mail Messages activity.

https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/move-outlook-message

[image]

Comment: Move outlook mail message works only on outlook app not on o365 web , so i used IMAP mail massage to delete the sent mail.